# Can MySQL .NET Connector 6 Be Used w/ Entity Framework 4?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Does anyone know if the MySQL .NET Connector 6 can be used w/ the Entity Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2?

Answer (score 0):

No, EF4 in Beta 2 only supports SQL Server 2005 & 2008 I believe.

More providers are on the way but aren't released yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Devart dotConnect for MySQL offers support for EF v4 Beta 2.